# Mapping keys into objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the object I have:

```
years = {1924:2, 1934: 10, 2010: 4}
```

I would like to transform this into:

```
years = [{year: 1924, items: 2}, {year: 1934, items: 10}, {year: 2010, items: 4}]
```

This is the code I came up with so far (which obviously doesn't work):

```
var years2 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < years.length; ++i) {
    years2.push({ years: [$key] })
};
```

I am stuggling to find the right way to access the unnamed keys and map these into their own objects.

(I am still learning JS and I know this is basics, but somehow cannot get my head around it.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create key value pairs from the object with Object entries and map them to new array

```js
const years = {1924:2, 1934: 10, 2010: 4}


const ans = Object.entries(years).map(([key,value]) => {
  return {year: key, items: value}
})

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*, before posting.

Comment: Thanks! that works and slowly start to make sense to me too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get entries, then convert to object with map

```js
const years = {1924:2, 1934: 10, 2010: 4}
const result = Object.entries(years).map(([year, items]) => ({year: year, items: items}))
console.log(result)
```